# Solve the equation : ${ x }^{ 2 }-10x+1=\sqrt { x } \left( x+1 \right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried to solve the equation below more and more , but I didn't get the way to solution .So, can you help me to solve this problem or at least  give me hints .

$${ x }^{ 2 }-10x+1=\sqrt { x } \left( x+1 \right) $$

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: like putting x^2 = a and tried to find out the value of a and then the value of x

Comment: Also, I tried to square the two sides , but , it didn't work at all

Comment: Well, you know that $\sqrt{x} = x^\frac{1}{2}$. So, you can write $u=x^\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: These are the kind of details we like to see in a post; it helps us understand what you've tried, or where your error lies, or to suggest what you haven't tried.  This (one) time I'll edit your post to include those details you've written in the comments.

Comment: If you square both sides you should end up with $x^4-21x^3+100x^2-21x+1=0$

Comment: that's right and then ??

Comment: You could try and factorise into 2 quadratics (this is possible, i checked)

Comment: I thought about this way , but , it is not efficient

Comment: I mean it takes time to factorise it

Comment: You could also take a look at this website which looks at forming a depressed quartic and solving that to work it out http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html

Comment: @user348056 Are you telling us that, after Cubbs squared both sides of the equation and posted the answer in the comments (and if you knew that was right, that's another item you should have posted with your claim to have squared both sides). You replied to the suggestion that you factor that expansion into two quadratics (which can be done) that it's not efficient, or, i.e. it takes too much time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the OP has dismissed suggestions made in comments, and suggests that they are not willing to try to follow any suggestions, if those suggestions require too much time/work.

Comment: Equation you get . see @Cubbs is symmetric, so you can apply the fact that if $x_0$  resolves equation, also its reciprocal value $\frac{1}{x_0}$ does.

Comment: Following $z^2=x$ one achieves $z^4-z^3-10z^2-z+1=0$.  Just playing around with the obvious candidates we achieve in very few time $(z^2+3z+1)(z^2-4z+1)=0$.  Period.

Comment: set $y=\sqrt{x}$, so equation will be changed to this: 
$$y^4-y^3-10y^2+y+1=0$$. 
Note: $y\geq0$

Comment: @amWhy , your way of speaking isn't polite , I didn't ask you particularly to solve the equation. Regarding wast of the time , You are now wasting your time on comments instead of solving the question . However , this kind of people is existent and we have to teach them how can they speak properly.

Comment: I thank you everyone help me in the solution

Comment: @user348056 I tried to help you by expressing **your** words in **your** post so you would not immediately be closed for lack of effort. Suggestions/hints were offered in the comments, but you answered only that you **wanted a solution that wouldn't take you too much time.** It is you that has been rude to have done so.  My words have been merely a mirror to reflect to you your own words and voice.

Comment: @amWhy, I don't love this kind of argument . You have  written in your profile "and please be nice not only to users you already know, but especially to newcomers to our site.". and you did the opposite .

Comment: Have a nice day, @user348056!  Good-bye.

Answer (score 4):

Write $y=\sqrt{x}$. Then the equation becomes
$$y^4-10y^2+1=y^3+y$$
that is,
$$y^4-y^3-10y^2-y+1=0$$
Let's try to factor this polynomials, in such a way as to get integer coefficients. Let's try something of the form
\begin{align*}
y^4-y^3-10y^2-y+1&=(y^2+ay+1)(y^2+by+1)\\
&=y^4+(a+b)y^3+(2+ab)y+(a+b)y+1
\end{align*}
(the choice of constant coefficients $1$ is simply a guess, since they could be both $-1$)
Thus we are looking for $a$ and $b$ satisfying
$$a+b=-1\qquad\text{and}\qquad ab=-12$$
so $a=3$, $b=-4$ work.

Note, moreover, that $y=x^{1/2}>0$, so we are looking for positive roots of these polynomials. The solutions of $y^2+3y+1=0$ are $\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which are both negative and so are not of our interest.

The solutions for $y^2-4y+1$ are $\frac{4\pm \sqrt{12}}{2}=2\pm\sqrt{3}$, which are both positive, and so the solutions for $x=y^2$ are $x=(2\pm\sqrt{3})^2$.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? Did I make any mistake?

Comment: If you see the comments above , there is someone called @amWhy

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-x%5E3-10x%5E2-x%2B1%3D0) agrees with you

Comment: I don't know his problem . I think he was down voting your incredible solution

Comment: Because , he didn't want any one to help me in the solution

Comment: @user348056 I did NOT down-vote this answer.  Stop rudely accusing me of things I did not do.

Comment: @Luiz - seriously, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: I said , I think

Comment: @user348056, Anyway, apparently you are a new user. I'd suggest taking a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4945/58818, and the whole thread which has good information. I would also suggest to try to stick to constructive comments.

Comment: (Louis, I had 171616 rep at the close of yesterday, and have gained 40 rep today, so my rep is now 171656. Had I downvoted you, my rep would be 1 pt less; anyway +1

Comment: @amWhy I don't think you downvoted me. I was simply interested if someone had found some mistake and downvoted it instead of just pointing it out (which is more common than we'd like, as you certainly know).

Comment: @user348056, (not only for you :-) read the advice after "Please, everyone:"  on the profile of user ... amWhy (oh I see, you alrady read it)